# Regex for alphanumeric and single spaces

Tags: regex

How to allow single spaces in between alpha+numeric words?

The regex I have used is `"^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` to

1. Disallow numbers in the start
2. Allow alphabets and numbers after one or more alphabet character

Example :

Allow

- `Google`,
- `Car 401`, Not currently allowed !
- `Car401`

Disallow

- `012 Avenue`,
- `Central   Park`,
- `34134`

Test: https://regex101.com/r/StK21o/2/

Comment: Can you give one or two examples of strings that you are trying to match? It's not quite clear from your question.

Comment: @skwidbreth: Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex which uses a negative look ahead to discard the string that starts with a digit, and otherwise captures the text, which can be only separated with one space only,

```
^(?!\d)[a-zA-Z\d]+(?: [a-zA-Z\d]+)*$
```

**Explanation of regex:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!\d)` - Rejects the match if the string starts with a number
- `[a-zA-Z\d]+` - Captures one or more alphanumeric characters
- `(?: [a-zA-Z\d]+)*` - Further captures zero or more single space separated alphanumeric characters
- `$` - End of string

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Izf7rk/1)**

Comment: Hi, it fails for "I am 1234"

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra: It works well for "I am 1234". Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/Izf7rk/2) It works for all cases. It doesn't allow just empty spaces neither in the beginning nor at end.

Comment: @Downvoter: My solution doesn't seem to fail for any case, so why downvote? Show me a case for which it doesn't work?

Comment: I am not sure why Angular doesn't allow "\d". However, I have used "^(?![0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$" Thanks!

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra: May be your Angular version isn't supporting `\d` in which case using `[0-9]` worked. Good at last it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This expression should do.

`^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(?:\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$`

### Rules

1. First character must start with an alphabet
2. Alphanumeric characters allowed from 2nd character onwards
3. 1 optional space within the string (does not end nor begin with space)

### Expression explanation

- `^` denotes beginning of the string
- `[a-zA-Z]` matches an alphabet
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` matches zero or more alphanumeric character(s)
- `(?:\ [a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` allows an optional group of string that begins with a space, follows by at least 1 alphanumeric character
- `$` denotes the end of string

https://regex101.com/r/3IHN6j/4

Comment: Hi, the suggested regex allows a space in the start and restricts the input for just two words.

Comment: I was just about to ask about leading spaces.

Comment: @skwidbreth : The leading spaces are taken care of, but not words more than 2 are allowed in this case.

Comment: @IncharaRaveendra Just updated the answer. I'm not sure if this is what you want cause I assumed that instead of first character must start with anything other than `0-9`, I made the first character to begin with an alphabet.